# Obtain ABSOLUTE lock on a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to (SQL query) obtain an 'absolute' lock on a SQL table in a SQL server management studio. By an 'absolute' lock I mean no other process in the system can do anything with that table. 
I tried **TABLOCKX** but it seems other processes can still access the table.

Comment: tablockx should obtain a lock which is exclusive to the table. What process "seems to be accessing" the table under tablockx? Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: To block everything including `nolock` queries you would need a `sch-m` lock which would require something like `alter table`.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to accomplish and then we can help you pick the correct lock for your scenario.

Comment: @BrianAtkins As stated, I just want to acquire a lock so that no process in the system can access it for any purpose.

Comment: @Xedni: The other process is a piece of code written in .net.

Comment: @MartinSmith Can you give me an example query?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
begin transaction 

Alter table TABLENAME

Alter column COLUMNNAME DATATYPE

waitfor delay '00:30:00'  --HOLDS LOCK FOR 30 MINUTES

rollback transaction
```

Comment: Not my downvote but locking the table in this way for 30 mins is likely to cause all sorts of problems as it holds locks on system table rows. You will be better explaining more about your system and why you think you need this.

Comment: I think I absolutely explained my use case. And why exactly would I need to that should not be the concern here. And not that its hard to observe that you can change the time for which you want the lock for. A downvote still remains an enigma. I hope someone responsible would be able to explain.